# How to load images using lazyload after page index changed in gridview?

Tags: jquery, .net, lazy-loading

Here is my function for **lazyload**.

I am using this to load images in **gridview**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $("img.lazy").show().lazyload({
            effect: "fadeIn",
            failurelimit: 0
        });
    });
```

My problem is images are not loaded after user changes **pageindex** of the gridview.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you have your gridview in updatepanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this, When update panel updates its contents all event binding lost so add those binding on update endrequest.

```
$(function () {
    LazyLode();
});
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
     LazyLode();
});
function LazyLode(){
     $("img.lazy").show().lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        failurelimit: 0
    });
}
```

The `PageRequestManager` is a javascript object which is automatically available if an `update panel` is on the page.

I hope It will help;